# When to use Actions in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I know the requirements when to use the Plugin, Workflows , but I cannot come across those cases or situations when I can use the Actions. Can anybody suggest to me a real time requirement as to when to use the action?

If possible, please demonstrate an "Action" with an example.

Answer (score 3):

One simple use is when you need to execute some server side code from JavaScript by clicking a button in the ribbon OR any where in the client side(not on an entity delete, update, create etc.... messages.) , then you need to create an Action.

e.g if you have to implement some logic and you feel it would be very complex Or not possible on client side (JavaScript), then you should just create an action, implement your logic in that action(server side) and call that action in JavaScript.

For more Info [Actions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531060.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another cool use case for actions is that they can be global. Unlike workflows where you must choose a specific entity that the workflow runs for, an Action can be global. This means that the same action could potentially be run for multiple entity types